# Use python to get hid report descriptor

Tags: python, usb, hid

I want to use hidapi to get hid report descriptor, but I can't find the right way

```
import hid

device = hid.device()
device.open(0x1234, 0x5678)
descriptor = device.get_feature_report(0,0)
device.close()
```

Encountered the following error
How can I modify?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\.spyder-py3\temp.py:18 in <module>
    descriptor = device.get_feature_report(0,0)

  File hid.pyx:358 in hid.device.get_feature_report

OSError: read error
```